# Fix for Scroll to the next div with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So I have [**this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7e9cogs/) which allows me to scroll between divs with the **previous** and **next** buttons, the script works well although I was trying to find a way to solve a little issue which is when I scroll normally with the mouse wheel or the scrollbar and then get back to scroll with the buttons, the buttons scrolls the page to where I left scrolling previously with the buttons, and I wanted this to continue where I am, for example, If I scroll with the mousewheel till the div nr.3, I want it to continue scrolling to the div nr.4 when I click on the next button. Maybe by creating a :visible statement or something would do the job, but I don't know how to write it. Here's the code

```
$('div.postSection').first();

$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      var t = $(this).attr('id'),
      that = $(this);

    if (t === 'nextButton' && $('.currentPost').next('div.postSection').length > 0) {
        var $next = $('.currentPost').next('.postSection');
        var top = $next.offset().top;

        $('.currentPost').removeClass('currentPost');     
        $(function () {
               $next.addClass('currentPost');
               $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.currentPost').offset().top-55 }, 'slow');

        });
  } else if (t === 'prevButton' && $('.currentPost').prev('div.postSection').length > 0) {
        var $prev = $('.currentPost').prev('.postSection');
        var top = $prev.offset().top;

        $('.currentPost').removeClass('currentPost');

        $(function () {
               $prev.addClass('currentPost');
               $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.currentPost').offset().top-55 }, 'slow');
        });
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monitor scrolling per item and mark the them with a class or data attribute to keep track of what's visible or not.

Or, what I just found, was a nice little selector extension to get items in the visible area (viewport - and it's named as such). Just get the first() or last() based on Next or Prev click and work with that.

Viewport: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

The extensions work like:

```
$currentPS = $('.postSection:in-viewport').first();
```

Then you just update you next and prev:

```
var $next = $currentPS.next('.postSection');

var $prev = $currentPS.prev('.postSection');
```

Seems to work pretty well: 
http://jsfiddle.net/j7e9cogs/2/

Comment: Thanks, yeah this works, but it only works If I am on halfway of the div on my online website. The divs on my website are bigger though. these are like posts

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean. If you extend these divs beyond both the top and bottom of the container, it still returns the visible one allowing prev() and next() to return the one you want next.

Comment: hmm.. yeah, that's strange. On my website is not working though :\ I guess I'll have to play with those values `below-the-fold` and `above-the-top` to try to fix this. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Got a publicly accessible link?

Comment: it's complicated because you'd have to create an account to access it

Comment: I've found out what was causing this bug,  it was `.top-55` I had that to create a space from the top because of my fixed menu bar now I've changed it to `0` and now it's working fine, but I still need that space because of the menu though. Do you know other ways to give that space in a different way? maybe with those parameters `below-the-fold` and `above-the-top` which I dony know how they work

Comment: Found it! I had to add `.top - 55` on the second block of code `$.abovethetop` on the Viewport selectors like this: `$.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        return top >= $(element).offset().top - 55 + $(element).height() - settings.threshold;
    };`